# Code to save account details and register based on payload

Tags: java, rest, spring

I have this flow for registering a user. They send an empty user account no to get a temp account no which then they use for verifying the OTP by email and phone. Both done they should register successfully and then have a permanent account no by external system.

**Service**

```
public Account saveAccount(Account account) {
        logger.info("Inside AccountService ");

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(account.getAccountNo())) {
            logger.info("Temp flow condition true");
            Account crmClientResponse = prepareDataForCRMLoginInquiry(account);
            Account response1 = null;
            if (crmClientResponse == null) {
                logger.info("CRM response null");
                
                response1 = proceedTempFlow(account);
            } else {
                logger.info("CRM response non null - Customer exists");
                throw new GeneralExceptionHandler(ErrorCodes.104.getValue(), ErrorCodes.104.toString());
            }
            if (response1 != null) {
                logger.info("Response from temp flow is not null");
                return response1;
            }
        } else {
            if (account.getContact() != null && account.getContact().get(0).getEmailId() != null) {
                return proceedEmailFlow(account);
            }
            if (account.getContact() != null && account.getContact().get(0).getMobileNumber() != null) {
                return proceedMobileFlow(account);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Account proceedMobileFlow(Account account) {
        logger.info("Temp flow condition false");
        // Retrieve the cached customer data for the given account
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(account.getAccountNo()).orElse(null);
        logger.info("cache customer {}", customer);
        Account response = new Account();
        if (customer != null && account.getAccountNo() != null) {
            logger.info("check otp table");
            // Validate the Mobile OTP
            com.dox.ail.base.db.model.Otp otp = otpRepository
                    .findOneActiveOtpRecordByAccountNoLatest(account.getEaseAccountNo());
            logger.info("otp {}", otp);
            if (otp == null) {
                logger.info("insert new first time mobile");
                otpRepository.insertAttempt(account.getAccountNo(), Integer.parseInt(verifyOTPAttempts),
                        Integer.parseInt(resendAttempts), account.getOtp().getType().toString());

                cnsClient.generateOTPCNS(account);

                response.accountNo(account.getEaseAccountNo());
                response.setIsTemp(true);
                
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setName(account.getContact().get(0).getName());
                contact.setEmailId(account.getContact() != null ? account.getContact().get(0).getEmailId() : "");
                contact.setMobileNumber(
                        account.getContact() != null ? account.getContact().get(0).getMobileNumber() : "");
                response.setContact(account.getContact());
                Otp otpresponse = new Otp();
                otpresponse.setType(account.getOtp().getType());
                otpresponse.setOtpDuration(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(otpDuration)));
//              otpresponse.setOtpNumber(account.getOtp().getOtpNumber());
                response.setOtp(otpresponse);
                return response;
            }

            if (otp != null && otp.getResendAttempts() >= Integer.parseInt(maxAttempts)) {
                // set to inactive
                otp.setStatus("Inactive");
                otpRepository.save(otp);
                throw new OtpMaxAttemptsReachedException("Max attempts reached");
            } else {
                otpRepository.updateAttempt(account.getAccountNo());
            }

            cnsClient.generateOTPCNS(account);

            response.setAccountNo(account.getEaseAccountNo());
            response.setIsTemp(true);
            
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setName(account.getContact().get(0).getName());
            contact.setEmailId(account.getContact().get(0).getEmailId());
            contact.setMobileNumber(account.getContact().get(0).getMobileNumber());
            response.setContact(account.getContact());
            Otp otpresponse = new Otp();
            otpresponse.setType(account.getOtp().getType());
            otpresponse.setOtpDuration(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(otpDuration)));
//          otpresponse.setOtpNumber(account.getOtp().getOtpNumber());
            response.setOtp(otpresponse);

            Customer cacheCustomer = customerRepository.findById(account.getEaseAccountNo()).orElse(null);
            if (cacheCustomer != null) {
                cacheCustomer.setMobileStatus(0);
                customerRepository.save(cacheCustomer);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

```
private Account prepareDataForCRMLoginInquiry(Account account) {
        Account customer = crmClient.retrieveCustomer(account);
        if (customer != null) {
            customer.setContact(account.getContact());
        }
        return customer;
    }
```

**RestTemplate**

```
@Component
public class CRMClientImpl implements CRMClient{

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CRMClientImpl.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private CRMRetrieveCustomerMapper mapper;
    @Autowired
    private RestClientImpl<RetrieveCustomerResponse> restClient;
    @Value("${crm.base.uri}")
    private String baseUri;


    @Override
    public Account retrieveCustomer(Account account) {
        logger.info("Inside CRMClientImpl: Start{}", account);
        RetrieveCustomerResponse response;
        Account responseAccount;
        String uri = baseUri + "retrievecustomer/";
        Map<String, String> headers = RestTemplateHeadersGenerator.getHeaders();
        RetrieveCustomerRequest request = mapper.createRetrieveCustomerRequest(account);
        logger.info("request in retrievecustomer {}", request);
        RestResponse<RetrieveCustomerResponse, StatusResult> restResponse = ailRestClient.doPost(uri, headers, request, RetrieveCustomerResponse.class);
        if (restResponse.getHttpStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            logger.info("call to retrievecustomer api is successful", restResponse);
            response = restResponse.getResponseBody();
            logger.info("Response Code:: {}",response.getResponseCode());
            if("0".equals(response.getResponseCode())) {
                responseAccount = mapper.mapResponse(response);
            }
            else {
                logger.info("else not succeeded");
                 return null;
                // TODO why exc
                //throw new AppException(ErrorCodes.111.getValue(), "", HttpStatus.METHOD_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else{
            throw new AppException(ErrorCodes.111.getValue(), "", HttpStatus.METHOD_FAILURE);
        }
        return responseAccount;
    }
}
```

mapper

```
@Component
public class CRMRetrieveCustomerMapper {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CRMRetrieveCustomerMapper.class.getName());
    public RetrieveCustomerRequest createRetrieveCustomerRequest(Account account) {

        RetrieveCustomerRequest request = new RetrieveCustomerRequest();
        String accountQuery = account.getContact().get(0).getEmailId();
        String mobile = account.getContact().get(0).getMobileNumber();
        if(!StringUtils.hasText(accountQuery)){
            accountQuery = account.getContact().get(0).getMobileNumber();
        }
        request.setAccountContactValue(accountQuery);

        CRMFilter filter = new CRMFilter();
        ArrayList<IncludeProduct> list = new ArrayList<>();
        IncludeProduct includeProduct = new IncludeProduct();
        includeProduct.setCode("EAS");
        filter.setIncludeProduct(list);
        request.setFilter(filter);
        return request;
    }

    public Account mapResponse(RetrieveCustomerResponse response) {
        logger.info("Activated routine path mapResponse");
        Account responseAccount = new Account();
        ArrayList<Result> resultList =  response.getResult();
        if(resultList.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        Result result = resultList.get(0);
        responseAccount.setEaseAccountNo(result.getAccountNumber());
        responseAccount.setPartyId(Long.toString(result.getCustomerId()));
        return responseAccount;
    }
}
```

response dto

```
@Data
public class RetrieveCustomerResponse {

    private String responseCode;
    private String responseDesc;
    private long count;
    private ArrayList<Result> result;
    private boolean lastPage;
    private String host;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date date;
}
```

request dto

````
@Data
public class RetrieveCustomerRequest {

    String accountContactValue;
    CRMFilter filter;
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

a lot of things:

1. `public Account saveAccount(Account account)`, seems this method in some cases return null, and this can lead to unnecessary null check after that If we are using Optional.
   by making the method as

   `public Optional<Account> saveAccount(Account account)` caller methods/process, not need to aware of null as return type.
2. If you are using slf4j as Logger framework.

   `logger.info("Inside AccountService ");` this log is very redundant and can be replaced with very efficient log, for example. `logger.info("saving account {}", someInfo)`, and slf4j is responsible to tell us in which class we exist. because the logger is defined as
   `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountService.class)`
3. `logger.info("Temp flow condition true");` overall your logs can be more efficient than the one that existed. for example here, we know that if this logged, then we are exist in the Temp flow, but better to log more informative things for example, `logger.info("Temp flow initialized");`
4. `Account response1 = null;`, you can give better name for response1, response naming usually put for response entities.
5. `private Account proceedMobileFlow(Account account)`, you can reduce line complexity by extracting other methods, make function responsibility more readable.
6. take a tip for life, `public class CRMClientImpl implements CRMClient`,, naming classes as prefixImpl is not a good idea. let's imagine someone else need to implement the interface/abstract class, what to get him a name? prefixImpl2 ?? seems not a good idea. (although you define it as @Component) do not forget that @Primary is in the corner waiting...